# Mysql create table sql multiple

Tags: java, mysql

Is it possible to get a output like

```
dbName  tableName  createSql
test    t1         create table t1 ( id int not null )
test    t2         create table t2 ( id int not null )
prod    t9         create table t9 ( id int not null )
```

using a simple sql query in mysql.

Answer (score 0):

You can either try to recreate the create statements from information_schema (nightmare but someone has probably done it); you can simply loop over all the table, do a show create and then summarize it accordingly; or you can write a SP to do this. Another option would be mysqldump -d.